# Использование встроенных методов ЯП в С4 ЕГЭ

Tags: информатика

Не снимут ли баллы за использование встроенных в язык программирования функций (`sort`, `reverse`, `include?`, и т. п.) вместо написания собственных, если требуется написать:

> Эф­фек­тив­ную, в том числе и по
> ис­поль­зу­е­мой па­мя­ти, про­грам­му

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сдавал ЕГЭ в прошлом году и писал C4 на Cи, используя как раз `qsort()`.  Разумеется, мне его почти не засчитали, разумеется я поехал на апелляцию и там доказывал, что не верблюд (причём проверяющие *буквально* просто смотрели, что мой код не такой, как в эталонном решении, и говорили — «у вас ошибка»). Доказал.

Если оно вам надо — пишите хоть на Brainfuck, но я бы порекомендовал писать всю программу самому на Паскале, чтобы у проверяющих не было вопросов, а если какие и будут, то убедить их в своей правоте будет *куда проще*.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, сказать это можно только залезнув в голову тем, кто проверяет ЕГЭ.
А вообще если в языке есть встроенные методы вроде sort и reverse, то школьник сильно врядли напишет свой велосипед, делающий ту же работу быстрее.

Comment: Вот, насколько мне помнится, кто-то на хэшкоде как раз таки и был проверяющим.

>А вообще если в языке есть встроенные методы вроде sort и reverse, то школьник сильно врядли напишет свой велосипед, делающий ту же работу быстрее. 

А может, в этом как раз подвох :)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, если б я проверял - я бы не снизил) Один из главных навыков в программировании - умение пользоваться готовыми решениями

Comment: Если в задаче написано - напишите сортировку пузырьком, а человек применил sort - то это не решение задачи и за такое решение ставиться должен ноль. А вот если сортировка часть большой задачи, тогда применение sort - самое оно.

Comment: @KoVadim, ага за такую задачу должен ставиться ноль, потому что внутри sort очень врядли сортировка пузырьком =D.

Ну тут понятно, что человек с некоторым количеством мозгов если попросили написать сортировку, напишет свою сортировку, а потом подпишет "ну вообще есть родной метод sort"